# What determines the order of lines in Javascript being read?

Tags: javascript, runtime

This example was given in a presentation of expecting 1, 2, 3 as the run order of these functions, but in reality it's 1, 3, 2. Curious why the setTimeout function would be run last?

```
console.log(1)
setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 0)
console.log(3)
```

Comment: Because settimeout is async and doesnt block execution

Comment: Easy enough, so it's because of that function specific, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Async callbacks, like the callback passed to `setTimeout()` above are put in a queue to be called when the main synchronous body of the script has run to completion.

So the order is:

```
console.log(1)
setTimeout() // but not the callback
// put callback in queue
console.log(2)

// take item from queue and run
() => console.log(2)
```

One consequence of this is that the time passed to `setTimeout` is the *minimum* time before the callback fires. If the main synchronous tasks take longer than that, the callback will fire late.

You can demonstrate this by running a long-running `while` loop. (But **please** never do this in real code)

```js
let start = Date.now()
let now = start
let then = now + 3000;
   
// set timer for 100ms
setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout fired ater", Date.now() - start, "milliseconds"), 100)

// slow while loop takes 3000ms
while (now < then){
  now = Date.now()
}
console.log("loop done")
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback to `setTimeout` is asynchronous, so it's probably registered to be fired*, but that takes long enough to register that `console.log(3)` will have had time to run by that point.

When dealing with asynchronous code, you often can't guarantee the exact order that it will run in.

*I honestly don't know the internals of `setTimeout`, and that would likely depend on the exact implementation used anyways. The point is its callback is run asynchronously.

Comment: Didn't realize setTimeout was async, thanks a lot! Neat

Comment: @DanFein Note that it would have to be. If it blocked, that would cause all sorts of problems. Also think about a function like `setInterval`, which is similar. If that blocked, unless it was self-terminating, it would necessarily freeze the entire site when used; except for what's updated by the callback.